# setframe in subclassed uibutton not adjusting frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance, uibutton

I made a subclass of UIButton, and I want to set a "padding".  I want the button's frame to always be 15 pixels wider on each side, than the text.

In the drawRect method, I set the frame of the button to be 30 px wider than the text's width.  But when I try to do this the frame does not get adjusted at all.  Is this frame getting adjusted after I change the frame of my uibutton?  How can I adjust the frame to set a padding?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
[self setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"submitBtn.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y-90, self.titleLabel.frame.size.width + 30, self.frame.size.height)]; 
}
```

Thanks for the answers!!

Comment: Don't set the frame in `drawRect:`. This will force the view to redraw it again and all kind of weird unintended things will happen.

Comment: Do you know where/when can I set it?

Comment: Pretty much everywhere else. Do it when the text is changed.

Comment: I put setFrame: in setTitle:, but it is not getting called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the `setTitle:forState:` method and adjust the frame there. You should also set the background image somewhere other than `drawRect:`. A good place would be the `initXXX` method.

The only thing you should do in `drawRect:` is actually render content for the view based on its current state. No state should be changed in `drawRect:`.

Comment: Thanks, this is my first time subclassing this way so I am trying to learn the basics.  I used drawRect: because it was the only method that I found that gets called.  I tried using the initWithFrame: method, it doesn't get fired for some reason.

Comment: What `initXXX` method are you calling to create the button? Override that one.

Comment: I just dragged the button onto my .xib file and changed the class to my uibutton subclass

Comment: I don't use IB so I can't help with that aspect. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, I actually just found it.  The initWithCoder method gets called.

Comment: Dang, it doesn't change when I put setFrame: in that method either.

Comment: Try the `initWithCoder:` method. That might be called when created from a xib. Edit: Oops - I missed your previous message.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer, you answered it, I just found out that my setFrame was doing nothing because I am using autolayout.  I'll ask another question about that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186908/can-i-use-setframe-and-autlayout-on-the-same-view  Here is my other question