# UITextView in UIView not resizing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, resize, uitextview

I have an UIView named _containerView and inside this UIView I have a custom UITextView named _codeTextView. When the app is loaded, these views occupies the whole screen, however, when the keyboard appears, I would like the screens to resize.

I have to following method when the keyboard appears:

```
- (void)keyboardAppears:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    _containerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 216.0f);
    _codeTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 290, 216.0f);
}
```

The containerView gets resized properly however, the _codeTextView in it does not resize and I really have no clue why it's not resizing. I've already tried changing various options and it's driving me crazy :(

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered to use autoresizing masks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just created a project with the scenario you described. setFrame worked for all views with Autolayout disabled, but not with Autolayout enabled.

Do you have **Autolayout** enabled for that View Controller? setFrame does not work well with autolayout.
You'll have to use constraints to programmatically adjust your views.
(answer from: [Can I use setFrame and autolayout on the same view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186908/can-i-use-setframe-and-autolayout-on-the-same-view))

You can find some help here: http://nszombie.com/2010/12/08/ConstraintBasedLayout.html