# Change a UIView Frame

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, cgrect, cgrectmake

I have set a `UIView` in my `storyboard` and make it an outlet.

```
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *testView;
```

In the `- (void)viewDidLoad` method, I want to change its frame like this

```
CGRect frame = self.testView.frame;
frame.size.height = 2;
self.testView.frame = frame;
```

But it does not work. Anybody can tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might **enabled the autolayout in your project** , if so the `setFrame` straightly won't work . [Check here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186908/can-i-use-setframe-and-autolayout-on-the-same-view)

**Solution :**

- Disable the autolayout, if you don't need any more
- Check the above link using with the autolayout .

Answer (score 0):

Look at the tiny circle to the left of the property. Is it filled in or hollow? If it's hollow, then it means that you have not connected this particular element of the storyboard to the file's owner.

If the circle is filled in, than the outlet IS connected to something on your storyboard. Just make sure it's connected to the right entity, namely the UIViewController (or subclass thereof) that you are declaring testView within.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its connected to your XIB  do the following after changing the view -

```
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing the height to high number and see if that make a difference. I have created demo project for changing and reverting the height. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/rshankras/StackOverflowUIView

Comment: I know if it happens in a new IBAction it works, but I want to change the frame in the method - (void)viewDidLoad

Comment: ViewDidLoad gets called even before the View is drawn and hence you don't see the change. You can place the code in layoutSubviews?