# UIView with animation not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'd like to make `MenuView` display with animation.

When I call -`showSideMenu`, `MenuView` does not appear.

How do I fix it?

**MenuView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingView : UIView

@end
```

**MenuView.m**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 240, 568);
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor turquoiseColor];
    }
    return self;
}
```

**MasterViewController.m**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MenuView* sideMenuView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem* menuButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(showSideMenu:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuButton;

    self.sideMenuView = [[MenuView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:self.sideMenuView];
}

- (IBAction)showSideMenu:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.sideMenuView.frame = CGRectMake(80, 0, 240, 568);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     }];
}
```

Comment: What does happen? Did you debug?

Comment: Check this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522949/change-a-uiview-frame/22523357#22523357**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things:

- Put an NSLog in the showSideMenu method. Does it actually fire?
- You animate the frame. **Do you have AutoLayout turned off for this view controller**?