# Resizing views using auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I have a view controller that contains a custom view with a UITableView just below it.

I am trying to figure out how I can make the table view resize to fill up the remaining space, when I change the height of the custom view in code. I want this done using auto-layout constraints!

And on top of the for some reason I cannot programatically resize the height of a custom view made with storyboard, when I do nothing happens.

Auto-layout is both evil and amazing. Please help me!

Comment: Did you use setFrame: to resize the custom view? If it has auto layout constraint setFrame: is not working.

Comment: Yes I used setFrame, so does setFrame get ignored totally if a constraint is set on the view? Does that mean you need to make an IBOutlet for the height constraint and do it that way?

Comment: Yes. One more thing you can do here. Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186908/can-i-use-setframe-and-autolayout-on-the-same-view

Comment: Wow, thanks I have never heard of that property before so I will give that a try!

Comment: I still can't get the result I want, auto-layout is just not cool sometimes.

Comment: Auto-layout is pretty good method. It just takes time to get familiar with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize auto layout views. You have to modify constraint's value.

I assume you already have constraints like below.
Make IBOutlet of NSLayoutConstraint in your view controller:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *headerHeightConstraint;
```

Connect header view's *height* constraint to it.
then, you can resize height of header view with:

```
headerHeightConstraint.constant = 100.0f;
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ok I will try that right now. Thank you for going to the trouble of providing an image, I appreciate it.

Comment: Wow.  Had *no* idea it was possible to create IBOutlets for constraints.  Thank you.