# CGRect's setFrame lost origin value on iOS 8.0

Tags: uiview, ios8, frame

The following code works perfectly on iOS 7.1

```
UIView *superView = self.superview;
[self removeFromSuperview];
CGFloat rightMarginWidth = self.rightMarginWidth ? self.rightMarginWidth : defaultRightMarginWidth;
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width + rightMarginWidth, self.frame.size.height);
//assign a new frame
self.frame = newFrame;
[superView addSubview:self];
```

However, on iOS 8.0, suppose newFrame is origin=(x=30, y=29) size=(width=127, height=34). After the assignment, `self.frame` became origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=127, height=34).

Why the "origin" value is lost here?

Comment: Why do you remove the view from superview, only to add it again? Just change its frame.

Comment: @LeoNatan Just change frame, without doing this will cause autolayout constraints conflict.

Comment: If there is autolayout, you should not be changing the frame.

Comment: @LeoNatan the autolayout was set by stroryboard

Comment: @DavidLiu any solution for this yet?Im also having this problem

Comment: @DevC Not yet, hopefully, more people will realize this problem.

Comment: @DevC unfortunately, no, please up vote this question.

Comment: This answer solved it for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13539782/697560

Answer (score -1):

If the view controller has autolayout constraints, you should add `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;`