# can't change subview position in UITableviewCell subclass

Tags: uitableview, ios8, cell

I have a table. Table has 1 simple custom cell. There is only label in this cell.
Here is code of cellForRow function:

```
MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
cell.myLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.myLabel.frame, 0, -20);
cell.myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

return cell;
```

Everything works fine except this:

```
cell.myLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.myLabel.frame, 0, -20);
```

Label don't want to move!
I found this problem in iOS8.

Anybody help please :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13539782/1928161 :)

The trick is to add

```
cell.myLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=YES;
```

Comment: This is the best answer. :D

Answer (score 0):

in **MyCell.m** file add **layoutSubviews** method and change **myLabel frame**

```
- (void )layoutSubviews {
// always try to set frame in layoutSubviews
[super layoutSubviews];
self.myLabel.frame = CGRectOffset(self.myLabel.frame, 0, -20);
 }
```

and please modify your code like this

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 static NSString *cellIdentifier;
 cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  cell.myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
cell.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];

return cell;

}
```

Comment: thanks! It solved my problem, but partially. If I scrolldown, then new cells appear with label, that don't move :(

Comment: modified my answer check once.

Comment: sorry, I need to use prototypes from table in storyboard. So using ...if (cell == nil)... is not for my situation