# How to tell a UIView what CGRect it goes in on a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've found and configured a `UIView` that works perfectly for what I'm trying to do, however I'm having a tough time configuring the `CGRect` for it.

**What I've got:**

1) `MyViewController.h/m`

2) `CustomUIView.h/m`

In interface builder, I added a `UIView` object and configured the AutoLayout constraints. In identity inspector, I set Custom Class to `CustomUIView`. I added an `IBOutlet` to `MyViewController.m`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomUIView *customUIView;
```

In `MyViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`, I use these commands to add `customUIView`:

```
[self.customView drawCustomViewInView:self.customUIView];
```

In `CustomUIView.m`, `drawCustomViewInView` has the following line, which I'm having a b***h of a time with:

```
customViewWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - (2 * STEPPER_MARK_HEIGHT_WIDTH);
```

Originally, the values for drawing `CustomUIView` were hard-coded, so I just made the `UIView` object the width of the screen and called it a day. That came back to bite me in the @$$ when I started testing different screen sizes.

How would I get `CustomUIView` to know about the rect I want it to draw in on `MyViewController`? I know this isn't that hard, but I can't ****ing figure it out. I've discovered `[UIScreen mainScreen]` won't get the job done for every screen size...I need to tell it the rect.

Comment: Did you set autolayout for `customUIView`? if yes, You need set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES` then `setFrame:`. However, when you do this, you still need to make sure that these automatic constraints can be satisfied with the rest of your constraints.

Comment: More here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186908/can-i-use-setframe-and-autolayout-on-the-same-view

Comment: Thank you! This looks very promising! I'll tinker with it in the morning and let you know how it goes.

Comment: THAT WAS IT! This is me right now--> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IS7Og1zvdy8 Thank you for your help on this. Throw that up as an answer and I'll get you 25 points :)

Comment: If you are adding the CustomView object through IB why are you adding another one programatically?

Comment: @Paulw11 Luan got me squared away. CustomView has a method that draws in a rect on MyViewController.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I still wonder why you are adding the object programatically via `addSubView`  if you have already added it via Interface Builder.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It might be a stray line from when I was messing around with it. I'll nuke it and see what happens. Thank you for raising this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding two lines to `MyViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` got me squared away:

```
self.customUIView.translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
[self.customUIView setFrame:self.customUIView.frame];
```

Those two lines enabled me to incorporate a custom `UIView` with its own drawing methods into a `UIViewController` via AutoLayout. Special thanks to Luan Nguyen for pointing me in the right direction.

A more in-depth discussion of this topic can be found in ["How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love AutoLayout"](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/03/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-auto-layout/).